# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression'_primaryCompleter.complete':InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1QZD.png)

this error is only on chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5yRJ.png)

this is the data request

soo any ideas I tried to upgrade to the latest flutter version but nothing changes

and one more thing I am using PHP and my SQL as backend